# Combining rows of a dataframe in python based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a list of indexes as follows -

1. 0,1
2. 2
3. 3,4,5
4. 6,7
5. 8,9

I want to be able to combine rows of this dataframe based on indexes above. [Old dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyssM.png). So, the result/output desired is
1st row of new dataframe is combination of 0 and 1. 3rd row is combination of 3,4,5 rows of old dataframe and so on based on list of indexes to be combined. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `Given a list of indexes as follows` - it is NOT list, it seems `Series`. How looks expected ouput? What means `combine` ? It is aggregation?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.